# JPQL Query results in multiple roundtrips to database even EAGER and JOIN FETCH

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Im trying to understand why my query results in 2 calls to database. In my understanding I have an EAGER loading with FETCH keyword in the query that should result in one roundtrip, but in below this isnt the case .. Grateful for any tips!

```
        TypedQuery<Recipe> query = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Recipe r" +
                "  LEFT JOIN FETCH r.ingredients ri LEFT JOIN FETCH r.author a WHERE r.id= :id ", Recipe.class);
        
        query.setParameter("id", id);
```

The Recipe Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipes")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@JsonSerialize(using = RecipeMetaSerializer.class)
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User author;


    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "recipe",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
    )
    private List<RecipeIngredient> ingredients;
}
```

First Join table RecipeIngredient:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipe_ingredients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(RecipeIngredientId.class)
public class RecipeIngredient implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Recipe recipe;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Ingredient ingredient;
.....
}
```

Second join table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Recipe> recipes;
    
}
```

The JPQL query results in following two calls to DB both containing **left outer join to table users**:

```
select recipe0_.id as id1_6_0_, ingredient1_.ingredient_id as ingredie4_5_0__, user2_.img_url as img_url2_7_2_, user2_.username as username4_7_2_ from recipes recipe0_ **left outer join recipe_ingredients** ingredient1_ on recipe0_.id=ingredient1_.recipe_id **left outer join users** user2_ on recipe0_.author_id=user2_.id where recipe0_.id=?

select recipe0_.id as id1_6_0_, user1_.username as username4_7_1_ from recipes recipe0_ **left outer join users** user1_ on recipe0_.author_id=user1_.id where recipe0_.id=?
```

I was hoping for a join to Users table once, not twice.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the second query is for `Recipe recipe` here

```
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredient {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Recipe recipe;
 
}
```

Just use `FetchType.LAZY`

```
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredient {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Recipe recipe;
 
}
```

You would not have the second query, if you use `entityManager.find()` method. The `recipe` will be already in the cache.

But for JPQL Hibernate considers that `recipe`, that is found in the first query, is not in the cache, so it gets it again (even it is the same `recipe`).

**Advice**

Always use lazy loading everywhere. It is impossible to disable eager loading in runtime. Also, it will be very hard to test everything, if you will want to change `eager` to `lazy`.

https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell

Comment: Thank you ! That works, I obviously still dont get all the perks of JPQL